# how to check first two characters in Sql Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code: `FR20155364714`

The first two characters of the ISIN code are referenced in `REF_ISIN`.

I want to control the first two characters of the isin code according to the `REF_ISIN` table. The data on SQL is called `REF_ISIN`. If the ISIN code is false, I enter the error code EC20 in a table called `Collection`.

How to implement this?

Comment: Can you not do something like `LEFT(colName, 2)` and check against them?

Comment: can do this : select case (left( codeisin,2) in (REF_ISIN) then CODE_ISIN 
else insert into ec20 error table) ?

Comment: I have no idea as I don't know what the tables look like/ what your query looks like. But to get the first two characters you can use `LEFT()` and then just check against them

Comment: Have a look at the `LEFT` function, or (especially if this is in the `WHERE`) `LIKE`. What have you tried, why didn't it work?

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSERT INTO`  :

```
INSERT INTO [ec20] (REF_ISIN)
   SELECT 'EC20'
   FROM REF_ISIN RF 
   WHERE LEFT('FR20155364714', 2) = RF.CODE_ISIN;
```